# delegate and declare variable receivedData in NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I want to create a NSURLConnection delegate in Xcode 4.5.2 for iOS because the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE)  suggests it. For now I am putting the following code (taken directly from the documentation) into my AppDelegate.m in the method `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

```
// Create the request.
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/"]
                        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                    timeoutInterval:60.0];
// create the connection with the request
// and start loading the data
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if (theConnection) {
    // Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
} else {
    // Inform the user that the connection failed.
}
```

How do I create the delegate in AppDelegate.h ?
Where and how do I declare the variable `receivedData`?

Comment: Don't do this. This is bad. You should create a new object that owns the NSURLConnection and is the delegate etc... You shouldn't be doing this kind of thing in AppDelegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing this in the AppDelegate, but just to make it work, here's what you need to do.

1) In your AppDelegate.h, replace the interface declaration with this ::

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate> {
    NSMutableData *receivedData;
}
```

2) In your AppDelegate.m, add this method ::

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [receivedData setData:data];
    NSLog(@"receivedData : %@", receivedData);
}
```

Comment: You should also implement `connectionDidFinishLoading:` and `connection:didFailWithError:`, otherwise you don't know when the download is complete.

Comment: ... and it should be `[receivedData appendData:data]` or you have problems if the data comes in chunks.

Comment: Can I do it in my ViewController and have it triggered by the user entering a URL in a textfield, so that the address is not apple.com? The viewcontroller.h already has `@interface BSViewController : UIViewController
<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIButton* chooseImage;` in it.

Comment: I suggested the above methods "just to make it work", he proabably shouldn't be doing this in the AppDelegate at all

Comment: But you should probably go through this before doing it: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

Comment: Do I make a whole new @interface...@end in ViewController.h or do I just add to the existing one, and if I just add to the existing one, how do I do it?

Comment: Just add to the existing one like this : @interface BSViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate, NSURLConnectionDelegate>